# D3 Focus+Context via Brushing not displaying scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to replicate [this Focus+Context via Brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367) example.  I'm including the same layout, but with a scatterplot instead of a line/area plot.

I started working off [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PyvZ7/7/) example I found which combines the area plot and a scatterplot.  However, when I scrap the area plot, I lose the zoom/focus capability.

My last step (thus far unsuccessful) is to make the brush (small focus bar on the bottom) actually respond to the main panel (make it adjust/zoom in when smaller time periods are selected in the brush).  The brush adjusts the axis as it should, but I just haven't been able to make the brush actually adjust/zoom the points on the main scatterplot.  I'm not trying plot anything in the brush - there will be a lot of points, so keeping the brush with a grey background and no points is fine.

here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fuqzp580/3/

Sidenote: I can't quite get the jsfiddle to work with the way I'm using `d3.csv`, so I coded up a slightly altered version with dummy data in lieu of using `d3.csv`.  However, I included the `d3.csv` code (commented out), just in case that could be a cause for my problem.

I'm new to `d3` so any pointers or ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with the dots zooming on the points in the main panel: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/3uwg92f8/1/

You were very close, I just made 3 small changes:

Firstly, uncommented the code you already had in `function brushed()` for selecting the dots

Secondly, defined `mydots` globally (since you were only doing it inside `initialize()` and it needs to be used beyond this scope). Added this on line 55:

```
var mydots = focus.append("g");
```

And last (and most importantly), I changed the definition for `xMap` from

```
xMap = function(d) { return x2(d.time); }
```

to

```
xMap = function(d) { return x(d.time); }
```

When brushing, it's the `x` scale that gets updated, not the `x2`

Comment: @Henry, it's a great answer. I was wondering, how can I edit the code such that the points will disappear the moment they pass through the y-axis?